# wp contact form 7 not working on safari browser

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

http://technologywisdom.com/devp/wp-lakecity-plating
my site includes simple contact form 7 Forms and these forms are not submitting on safari Browser/Mac !
AJAX Loader keeps on loading and not send the form . Please Check and Guide

Comment: Please deactive other plugins except contact form 7 and check work or not.

Comment: What errors are displayed within the Chrome Tools console log upon submitting?

Comment: I did and found the issue is because of MultiLine files for Contact Form 7 Plugin that I am using , may be its Js conflicting with other plugin. But I need that for my form as I want the user to have relaxation of uploading multiple files

Comment: Thank you David.J your answer got me to the right Place to fix the error in plugin but that also didn't solve my problem. I have done it with disabling the ajax. Thanks Others as well for helping. This platform is such as nice place to learn and solve the bugs.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably due to a conflict between plugins/theme. Try deactivating all other plugins and switching to the default theme.
Otherwise you can also disable Ajax load just simply go to Plugins, Contact Form 7, click on edit and locate the wp-contact-form-7.php file then make the amendments below,

```
define( 'WPCF7_LOAD_JS', true);
```

with

```
define( 'WPCF7_LOAD_JS', false);
```

Comment: But i am uploading a file in my forms and make this changing , not letting me do that

Comment: This method didn't solve my problem but I did it done by disable ajax loader with a plugin called Contact Form 7 Controls.

Comment: This only happens when you attach a file with it? Because without file its working perfectly fine. If its because of file attachment then kindly check your file type and file upload size from your contact form 7 backend